# "Просто" в значении "прямо"

Tags: грамотная-речь, выбор-слов, разговорная-речь

Невероятно часто встречаю у одного автора-любителя повторение наречия ***просто*** в значении ***прямо***.

*Еле-еле заметная дверь, расположенная **просто** в стене, вела в непроходимые лабиринты, которые в итоге заканчивались выходом на поверхность.*

Не пойму: это ошибка? Звучит несколько простонаречно. Или это, наоборот, признак "высокого штиля"?

---

Ответов я увидела несколько, причём услышала такие точки зрения:

1. ***Просто*** в данном контексте означает ***бесхитростно***, ***незатейливо***.
2. Автор неправильно употребил это слово.

В таком случае я задаю вопрос заново, причём уже добавляю сюда варианты, полностью скопировав их - в прошлый раз я перефразировала. Там была вовсе не дверь, так что споры велись уже по поводу предложения, неправильно составленного *мной*, а не автором.

> *Рычаги управления, сжимаемые мёртвыми руками, продолжали двигать машину вперёд. Просто в лапы стального монстра. **Просто** в белый дым.*
>
> *Затем **просто** передо мной загорелся обзорный экран, передававший мне изображение с внешних камер.*
>
> ***Просто** во тьму. Нырнул в неё, словно рыба в омут.*
>
> *Именно от него, из центральной части города, расположенной **просто** в стене, вёл тоннель к Лифту.*

Действие происходит в подземном мире, так что "центральная часть города, расположенная в стене" - вполне нормальное явление.

И всё же, господа, что объединяет эти случаи? Неужто в каждом из вариантов ***просто*** означает что-то своё? Зачем оно нужно? Или это авторское "слово-паразит", от которого нужно избавляться?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Рычаги управления, сжимаемые мёртвыми руками, продолжали двигать машину вперёд. Просто в лапы стального монстра. Просто в белый дым.

Возможно, употребляя слово *просто*, автор намекает на что-то нам неизвестное, но скорее всего, он **просто** не умеет пользоваться этим словом.

Мой вариант: "Прямо в лапы стального монстра. В белый дым."

> Затем просто передо мной загорелся обзорный экран, передававший мне изображение с внешних камер.

Слово *просто* здесь неуместно. Корректо: "затем прямо передо мной" или **просто** "затем передо мной".

> Просто во тьму. Нырнул в неё, словно рыба в омут.

Слово *просто* здесь неуместно. Корректо: "прямо во тьму". Могло бы быть: "просто нырнул".

> Именно от него, из центральной части города, расположенной просто в стене, вёл тоннель к Лифту.

Мы можем говорить о стене как о поверхности, и тогда отвесный горный склон можно назвать стеной. Но если мы говорим, что что-то **расположено в стене**, то представляется стена как объем, и тогда гору нельзя называть стеной, а в нормальной стене город (или его часть) не поместится.

Не занаю, что в данном предложении могут подчекнуть слова *просто* и *прямо*, поэтому **просто** опукаю их: "часть города, расположенная в горе".

Answer (score 2):

Я понимаю такое употребление в значении "бесхитростно, незатейливо". Словари не относят это значение к разговорному или просторечному. Например: "держать ключи просто в кармане", "оставлять машину просто под открытым небом". Слово "прямо" имеет другой оттенок значения ("подчёркнуто", "нарочито" и т.п.).

Upd. После уточнения вопроса.

> Или это авторское "слово-паразит", от которого нужно избавляться?

Согласен теперь с таким выводом.

Answer (score 1):

Да, предложение  стилистически (да и по смыслу) не очень корректное, в связи с чем и возникают разные вопросы,  согласна с Alex_ander.

Как вариант: **Дверь, еле заметная в стене, вела в непроходимые лабиринты, которые в итоге заканчивались выходом на поверхность.**

**ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ**

1) Частицы ***просто*** и ***прямо*** имеют определенное значение (соотнесенное с мотивирующими прилагательными ***простой*** и ***прямой***) и употребляются только при необходимости.

2) Они не так часто заменяют друг друга, **правильность сочетания** приходится определять на слух, например:

**Прямо   во тьму.  Просто нырнул в неё, словно рыба в омут.**

Пояснение

**Прямо**   во тьму (**по прямой**, непосредственно в **окружающее** пространство).

Просто (**без дополнительных движений, безо всяких ожидаемых сложностей**) нырнул в неё, словно рыба в омут.

Answer (score 0):

**Дверь** практически всегда бывает **в стене**, поэтому ни "просто", ни "прямо" не проясняют, что же особенного в таком её нахождении. Видимо, автор пытался удивить тем, что в загадочный лабиринт вела "*просто дверь* в стене", а акцент получился на *местоположении* двери, что и вызывает у читателя лёгкое недоумение. Видимо, можно было и вовсе обойтись без лишних слов и запятых:

> Еле-еле заметная дверь в стене вела в непроходимые лабиринты...

Comment: Хорошо, а если вход в лабиринты "расположен просто в стене"? Тогда какое будет значение?

Comment: Тоже непонятно, зачем это слово: выбор простых вариантов невелик (если не "дверь", то кроме стены есть ещё пол и потолок).

Comment: Наверное, нужен более широкий контекст для понимания. Не всякая дверь ведёт в непроходимые лабиринты, которые заканчиваются выходом на поверхность. Но дверь дома — это обычно не просто дырка в стене. Предполагается ещё какое-то оформление (козырёк, крыльцо, наличники и т.п.). Вот как раз без всего этого можно сказать "просто". Кстати, "еле-еле заметная" тоже на это намекает.